# How Jsoup can return readable address in this case?

Tags: java, jsoup, reverse-geocoding

I thousands of data consisting of latitude longitude information. I am trying to build a desktop application that requires the latitude longitude to converted to human readable address. I figured that Jsoup is used for such task.

I expected "Belmani, Madhya Pradesh 486669, India" to be printed in console by code below(but it seems that even posting also had not been done):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude")
              .data("lat", "24.2")
              .data("lon", "82")
              .userAgent("Chrome")
              .post();
   System.out.println(doc.getElementById("address")); // should print html source of address returned
```

I tried for this much. How can Jsoup accomplish this chuck of task? Sample code for above case?

Comment: it works as seen [here](http://pastebin.com/yfL5eXQt) while in exactly same way it's NOT working as shown [here](http://pastebin.com/qrx6VUxS). Puzzling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send data through URL parameters:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude/?lat=24.2&lon=82").get();
System.out.println(doc.getElementById("address"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The website works with `GET` parameters (url params) instead of `POST`.

You can use your example exactly as you have it, but swap `.post()` for `.get()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/find-address-from-latitude-and-longitude")
            .data("lat", "24.2")
            .data("lon", "82")
            .userAgent("Chrome")
            .get();
    System.out.println(doc.getElementById("address"));
}
```

That avoids you needing to manually needing to build URL, as Alexey's answer implies.

That gives (you can finish the parsing to strip the unnecessary info):

```
<span id="address"><span class="label">Address:</span><span class="value">Belmani, Madhya Pradesh 486669, India</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Use firefox poster and figure out how you need to pass on the parameter and which method to be used get or post and then change your code accordingly.